# ExtJS Grid - Display Multiples rows in one row

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2, extjs-grid

I am having below json data in ExtJS store. I am using Ext.grid.Panel to show this content with colum Name and Phone.

> {
>           "name": "Doris Ryan",
>           "phone": "1-536-934-9500"
>       },
>       {
>           "name": "Nissim Hines",
>           "phone": "1-937-975-0044"
>       },
>       {
>           "name": "Walter Gallegos",
>           "phone": "863-4112"
>       },
>       {
>           "name": "Miranda Boyd",
>           "phone": "1-820-817-5049"
>       },
>       {
>           "name": "Sonya Booth",
>           "phone": "468-0669"
>       },
>       {
>           "name": "Rose Steele",
>           "phone": "1-581-774-8023"
>       },

So with this I am getting Grid in below format

> ```
> Name              Phone
> Doris Ryan        1-536-934-9500
> Nissim Hines      1-937-975-0044
> Walter Gallegos   863-4112
> Miranda Boyd      1-820-817-5049
> ```

But what i want to display the content in Grid as described below

> ```
> Name              Phone            Name              Phone
> Doris Ryan        1-536-934-9500   Nissim Hines      1-937-975-0044
> Walter Gallegos   863-4112         Miranda Boyd      1-820-817-5049
> ```

User is able to edit the phone number. So also share details on how will I handle the updates on grid.

Comment: I doubt this is possible without bringing the data into the format expected by the grid (two names and two numbers per record).

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this is to change how you assemble the data in the model, and then you also change the exposure via the grid.

ExtJS does not have the property to automatically replicate two rows of records in a single row.

Crete a model like this:

```
Ext.define('YourApp.model.yourFeature.Model', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [{
        name: 'Phone1',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Name1',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Phone2',
        type: 'string'
    }, {
        name: 'Name2',
        type: 'string'
    }]
});
```

Define your data, like your question:

```
var data = [{
    "name": "Doris Ryan",
    "phone": "1-536-934-9500"
}, {
    "name": "Nissim Hines",
    "phone": "1-937-975-0044"
}, {
    "name": "Walter Gallegos",
    "phone": "863-4112"
}, {
    "name": "Miranda Boyd",
    "phone": "1-820-817-5049"
}, {
    "name": "Sonya Booth",
    "phone": "468-0669"
}, {
    "name": "Rose Steele",
    "phone": "1-581-774-8023"
}]
```

So you make a kind of odd / even logic to abound your record.